# Is there an elegant way in sqlite to select a single column in a self join?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT mindate.rID
FROM
    (SELECT rID, mID, count(mID), min(ratingDate), stars
    FROM rating
    GROUP BY rID, mID
    HAVING count(mID) >1) 
AS mindate,
    (SELECT rID, mID, count(mID), max(ratingDate), stars
    FROM rating
    GROUP BY rID, mID
    HAVING count(mID) >1) 
AS maxdate
WHERE mindate.stars > maxdate.stars
```

This is an example query that doesn't work, because I can only select either "mindate.rID" or "maxdate.rID" or it gives me an "amiguous column name - error", eventhough either could be the entry I need. The only way I see to solve it is do use "SELECT *", but there must be a more elegant way to solve it, isn't there?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your query is malformed, because the `GROUP BY` keys don't match the `SELECT` columns.  There is probably a simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sqlite allows that - see https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause

Comment: What is your query supposed to do? Please elaborate. And what is the table's unique key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQLite you can select both columns if they are qualified by the table's name/alias:

```
SELECT mindate.rID, maxdate.rID
```

If you face such a problem I suspect that it has nothing to do with SQLite but with the tool or the programming language that you use to run this query.
In any case it's a good practice not to have in the results 2 columns with the same name so you should alias them:

```
SELECT mindate.rID minID, maxdate.rID maxID
```

See a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mcNtEAijBqTUB4JseDkRX8/1).
If what you want is to return only one of the 2 columns based on some condition then use a CASE expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN <condition> THEN mindate.rID ELSE maxdate.rID END
```